# Perl regex to match phone numbers

Tags: regex, perl

Regex:

```
\b(\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})?[-.]?\d{3}[-]?\d{4}\b
```

My input file has two types of phone numbers. One, whose first 3 digits are enclosed in parenthesis and the other with no parenthesis. 
Eg:

```
"(201)-450-4479" ,"234-345-3456"
```

I want to match both type of phone numbers using alternate operator.

Please suggest me. What modification is required for above mentioned expression to get the intended result?

Comment: Except the first `\b` your regex seems correct.

Answer (score 1):

`\b` matches at a word-nonword boundary. If such a boundary should appear before `(`, it must be preceded by a word character, not whitespace or nothing.

Cf.

```
print /\b\(/ ? 1 : 0 for '(', ' (', 'a(';
```

Remove the starting `\b` from the regex, or replace it with

```
(?x: \b | \s | ^ )
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply. Your comment was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use this:

`(\(?\d+\)?\-\d+\-\d+)`

or using the alternate operator:

`(\d+\-\d+\-\d+|\(\d+\)\-\d+\-\d+)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Both of your above expressions are yielding expected results. I am just curious to understand what was wrong with my expression?

Comment: Could you please suggest me what's wrong with this expression "((\d+|\(\d+\))\-\d+\-\d+)" . 
Result of this exp is "(201)-340-2011 (201) 234-345-3456 234 (201)-450-4479 (201)".  
Duplicates of first three digits are printing after every successful match.

Comment: @Pramod - first you need to escape the `(` characters like this: `\`(`

Comment: @Pramod but that regex, when escaped properly, will capture all digits if parentheses are not present, or the first 3 digits only if they are. I don't think that's what you want

Comment: Indeed i have escaped the parentheses using backslash but i don't know why those escape characters are not visible in the comment. I am just trying to avoid the redundant characters in the expression,